# How do I disable snap-to in drawings in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

How do I draw lines in a Word 2007 drawing without them automatically snapping to the nearest whatever? Currently I'm forced to draw them to one side, then drag them into place.

Please tell me there's a better way...

Answer (score 2):

Hi: you just have to use the sinewave-like line and hold down the shift key to get a straight line. The sine wave like line is normally used for drawing graphs and waves but it becomes a straight line when you hold down the shift key.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Office support article:
[Turn the snap to grid and snap to object options on or off](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/turn-the-snap-to-grid-and-snap-to-object-options-on-or-off-HA010235261.aspx#BMwo)

> 1. Click the shape or object in the document.
> 2. Under **Drawing Tools** on the **Format** tab, in the **Arrange** group, click **Align**, and then click **Grid Settings**. If you do not see the Drawing Tools or Format tabs, make sure that you clicked a shape or an object.
> 3. Do one or both of the following:
>            [...]
>
>    - To position shapes or objects to grid lines that go through the vertical and horizontal edges of other shapes or objects, under **Object Snapping**, select the **Snap objects to other objects** check box.

Comment: Thanks, totally doesn't work for me unfortunately, maybe there's a bug :(

Comment: Are you editing an existing document or does this happen also when you create a brand new one?

Comment: New document, default settings already have snap off for other objects and grid.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the grid settings isn't enough, alas!
A detailed discussion of this tricky issue, and some workarounds, is described here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/word/thread/b6c3a09a-938e-4519-8d41-e50c47463517/

Comment: Good first answer.

Comment: Could you possibly expand upon the relevant workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on a mac, you can hold the command key down while moving the object to disable snapping.